# Containers IP accessible in local network Docker for Windows (Hyper-V)

Tags: windows, networking, docker, local, hyper-v

i'm using Docker for Windows with Hyper-V

I want my containers to be accessible in my local network (192.168.0.0/24) with their own IP (for example 192.168.0.53 and 192.168.0.54), i've tried to change networks Hyper-V settings ('DockerNAT') to 'external' , but my containers are only accessible in my office with my host's ip (192.168.0.90).

How can I do that simple thing (without reverse proxy)?

Answer (score 0):

You can add more IP to the windows DockerNAT interface.
Then bind your container ports to one IP from DockerNAT int.

You will need different IP range then yout current IP 192.168.0.0/24.
For example you can use 192.168.1.0/24 by assingning IP 192.168.1.1.

How to add more IP to one network interface:
http://tunecomp.net/windows-10-multiple-ip-addresses/

Then simply bind ports like this.

```
ports:
 - 192.168.1.1:80:80
```

You will have htpp on default port on 192.168.1.1 :-)

Drawback: you will need a sign that second IP every time after Docker restart.